# ExtensionLevel added by iText when generating PAdES LTV

Tags: pdf, itext

According to PAdES part4 (LTV) document:

```
The extensions dictionary (see ISO 32000-1 [1] clause 7.12) should 
include an entry:
    <</ESIC
        <</BaseVersion /1.7
        /ExtensionLevel 1 >>
    >>
to identify that a PDF document includes extensions as identified in the 
current document.

NOTE: Use of DSS as specified in Annex A.1 may also be identified by:
    <</ADBE
        <</BaseVersion /1.7
        /ExtensionLevel 5 >>
```

But, when generating LTV signatures using iText (java version 5.4.5), it adds the following extension:

```
<</ESIC
    <</BaseVersion/1.7
    /ExtensionLevel 5>>>>
```

Note that it is neither ESIC ExtensionLevel 1 nor ADBE ExtensionLevel 5.
It seems to me to be a mix of both (but obviously I can be wrong).

Is this the correct extension ? 
If so, does it mean that it adds to PAdES LTV some new elements added by Adobe's ExtensionLevel 5 ?

Or should this extension be one of the extensions that appear in the PAdES part4 document ?

I've seen a PAdES LTV file generated by Acrobat that contains an extension ADBE ExtensionLevel 8, so I understand that the two extension values that appear in the PAdES LTV document are not the only valid ones.

Comment: There are contradictions between PAdES and the PDF specification. Which extension you use depends on politics more than on technical reasons. This should be solved in 2016 with PDF 2.0 (ISO-32000-2).